# QGIS 2.12.0 WFS bounds settings

Tags: qgis

Does anyone know the difference in disable 'Cache Feature' and 'Only request features overlapping the current view extend'. The result seems to be the same. I would expect the disabling of 'Cache Feature' to dynamically load WFS features when panning or zooming the map.

[image]

Comment: My guess would be the cache option is strictly for caching the features once they are visible in the current view, and the "current view extent" check box is an additional optimization parameter to only request those features within current view extent instead of the layers of features outside the current view.